# Can the null space of a sparse matrix have a set of basis that is sparse?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Suppose we have a linear system $Ax=b$ in GF(2), where $A$ is sparse. Its solution is $x = Tz + x_0$.

It is apparent that $T$ is not unique, then is there a way to find a T that is as sparse as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the number $n$ of columns of $T$ is fixed at the dimension of the null space of $A$ (otherwise we could cheat by adding extra columns of $0$'s to $T$).    Thus the columns of $T$ are a basis of the null space of $A$ ($x_0$ and $b$ are irrelevant).

If $T_1$ is one possible $T$, the others
are $T_1 S$ where $S$ is an arbitrary invertible $n \times n$ matrix.  Since there are only finitely many invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $GF(2)$, one (not particularly efficient) algorithm is to enumerate all possibilities.